# Calculating annual percentage rate when repayment amount is not constant

Tags: algorithm, finance

I need to calculate APR for loans.  Constant repayment loans were covered clearly here [Calculating annual percentage rate (need some help with inherited code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102476/calculating-annual-percentage-rate-need-some-help-with-inherited-code)

My problem is where the repayment amount is not constant.  The monthly repayments can differ and therefore Newton-Raphson does not seem applicable.

The formula is still 0 = loan amount - sum[Rp/(1+x)^p] where Rp is the repayment amount for repayment p.  There are n repayments.  Is there a way to solve this or is there a good way to make a good second guess to x based on the results of previous guesses?

Comment: What does the repayment amount depend on? How is it calculated?

Comment: Can't you recalculate after each payment?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're given the Rp values and want to calculate x.  You can just use Newton-Raphson as before - the question you linked to showed you how to do that.

For this one, you just need to change your F(x) and F'(x) functions.

F(x) = loan amount - sum[Rp/(1+x)^p]
You'll have to write code with a little loop in it to do the sum.

F'(x) = + sum[-p*Rp/(1+x)^(p+1)]
A little loop there and you're set.

Comment: `F'(x) = + sum[-p*Rp/(1+x)^(p+1)]` how did you get + in the front